# Django form validation working unexpectedly?

Tags: django

I have this form in my view:

```
joinform = JoinProjectForm(request.POST)
            print(request.POST)
            print(joinform)
            if joinform.is_valid():
                joinkey = joinform.cleaned_data['joinkey']
                project = Project.objects.filter(joinkey=joinkey).first()
                project.users.add(request.user)
                return redirect('problemdashboard:problem-dashboard', project_id=project.pk)
            else:
                joinform = JoinProjectForm()
```

And this is my model:

```
class Project(MainAbstractModel):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25, default="")
    joinkey = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)
```

Now what I don't understand is, why is the form validation returning False? It says that a project with that joinkey already exists, but I'm not trying to create a new project with that joinkey, I simply want to add an user to the project with the joinkey that the user inputs in the form. What am I missing here?

Oh and the form itself is very simple:

```
class JoinProjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['joinkey']
```

Comment: Add a user to the product or project? if product then show the model for the product.

Comment: Oh, it was a typo, PROJECT, I don't have a product model

Answer (score 0):

Error is being caused by the `null=True, unique=True` in:

```
joinkey = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)
```

This is checking that every `Project` has a unique `joinkey`, if not then you will get 'a project with that joinkey already exists' error.

Since you have `null=True` and `unique=True`, django is considering `None` as a unique entry, remove `null=True`.

Comment: But I don't want to allow multiple projects to have the same joinkey.

Comment: unfortunatelly the is_valid still returns false, I removed the is_null and set a default of "0000000" (because I could not remove the is_null otherwise), and the same behaviour persists. Is_valid is still False

Comment: you cannot have a default as it will not be a unique

Comment: Can you tell why you need null=True?

Comment: But I'm not creating a new project. I simply need to add an user to an existing project with the form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214324/discussion-between-heisaif-and-justadudetryingtocode).